# I want to add interstitial ads to my android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads, interstitial

**(When user open GalleryActivity show interstitial ads) I want to add admob interstitial ads to my android studio project. I add banner ads to this but, I don't know add interstitial ads to this Activity. please help me to complete this project.**

```
public class GalleryActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
    GalleryActivity activity;
    ActivityGalleryBinding binding;

    AppLangSessionManager appLangSessionManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_gallery);
        activity = this;

        appLangSessionManager = new AppLangSessionManager(activity);
        setLocale(appLangSessionManager.getLanguage());

        AdsUtils.showGoogleBannerAd(activity,binding.adView);
        initViews();

    }

    public void initViews() {
        setupViewPager(binding.viewpager);
        binding.tabs.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewpager);
        binding.imBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < binding.tabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TextView tv=(TextView) LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null);
            binding.tabs.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);
        }

        binding.viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
        createFileFolder();
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer
[official](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) document for interstitial ad

Follow below steps to display interstitial ad

1. Declare and initialize InterstitialAd

   ```
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
   ```

   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

   ```
      InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
        // an ad is loaded.
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
        // Handle the error
        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
        mInterstitialAd = null;
      }
    });
   ```
2. If adLoaded display it to user

   if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
   mInterstitialAd.show(MyActivity.this);
   } else {
   Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
   }